# Adobe AIR - Save image on hard drive

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I found the below snippet to save an image to a specific folder with Adobe AIR.

How to modify it that the ["Save As"](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-3cEqBBRSSMA/TXjito4qXvI/AAAAAAAAAL0/LWje8LYzJpI/s1600/demo10.png) OS-window comes up first? (So users can choose where to save the image on the hard-drive)

```
var arrBytes:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bmd);
    var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(folderName + "/" + fileName + fileNum + ".png");
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    //
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeBytes(arrBytes);
    fileStream.close();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [File.browseForSave](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForSave%28%29):

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

var imgBytes:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bmd);
var docsDir:File = File.documentsDirectory;
try
{
    docsDir.browseForSave("Save As");
    docsDir.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, saveData);
}
catch (error:Error)
{
    trace("Failed:", error.message);
}

function saveData(event:Event):void 
{
    var newFile:File = event.target as File;
    if (!newFile.exists) // remove this 'if' if overwrite is OK.
    {
        var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(newFile, FileMode.WRITE);
        stream.writeBytes(imgBytes);
        stream.close();
    } 
    else trace('Selected path already exists.');
}
```

The [manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/) is always your friend :)

BTW, I see you're relatively new here - welcome to StackExchange!  If you find my answer helpful, please be sure to select it as the answer.

Comment: Selected. Thank you very much. Btw: Is there a "fastest way" to save an image to drive from AIR? By encoding a bitmap of 2800px x 2800px I always got a delay till it's saved - is it normal?

Comment: Glad it helped.  The delay is with encoding (not file writing).  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509554/fast-or-asynchronous-as3-jpeg-encoding) and the fastest of them all [here](http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/benchmark/).

Comment: @NRohler - That blooddy encoder looks really good! Unfortunately, I downloaded the swc and it doesn't seem to compile correctly. FDT can't parse it correctly either. Is there an older version anywhere that works okay?

Comment: @jowie I've never tried that SWC with an FDT project.  You might want to try contacting Nick (or Powerflasher) directly.

Comment: @NRohler thanks but I've tried it in Flash directly also, and it won't compile when I try to access its commands. It sits alongside a few other swc files but is the only one that won't work.