# Saving an Image from a Flash application During Runtime?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm having a difficult time finding any ActionScript that will do the trick of saving an image during runtime.

It's a Flash application where the user can design something, then send it in (to me) for publishing (I figured the best way to do that would be to take a picture JPEG of their finished design using some sort of ActionScript and then save it to my Web Server). I've searched around and found a few examples, but none of them seem to work.

Any light on this would be greatly appreciated!

Aaron

Comment: In general you would get the bitmapData of your containing MovieClip, JPEG encode it, then URLLoad it to your server. Equally important though is having a server page to process the request, what are you running on your server backend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509554/fast-or-asynchronous-as3-jpeg-encoding  - I used this expample from that question http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-tutorial-an-asynchronous-jpeg-encoder a while ago for an app, and it worked like a charm

Comment: @ToddBFisher I've been using a PHP script for my file transfer from applications to my server, which has worked great so far. I just can't seem to get the JPEG Encoding Class or anything to work in Flash.

Comment: @Evert Thank you for the tutorial! It seems a little more intense than I need it, is there anything a little more simple that sends the bitmap info to a PHP file transfer script or something similar?

Comment: The source code is at the bottom of it - it is pretty straight forward to implement: include the library, create an encoder object, pass a movieclip to it as bitmap data and post the encoded image to a php / .net page to save it on your server. The asynchronous version also exposes a few events that are useful for error handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was the simplest example that I found when I worked on a similar project:

It needs the as3corelib to be installed

https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

the problem with saving large jpgs was the synchronous nature of the encoder that would freeze the entire application while it ran, and hence it was replaced by the asynchronous library mentioned in the earlier comment

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;

var jpgSource:BitmapData = new BitmapData (sketch_mc.width, sketch_mc.height);
jpgSource.draw(sketch_mc);

var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(jpgSource);

var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("jpg_encoder_download.php?name=sketch.jpg");
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");
```

PHP STUFF - this writes it to the screen, but it could just as easily save the file.

```
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    // get bytearray
    $jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

    // add headers for download dialog-box
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['name']);
    echo $jpg;
}
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! I'll have to work on the PHP saving to the server, but excellent start.