# Thread or background processing in actionscript

Tags: multithreading, actionscript

I know that Actionscript is not multi-threaded. But, I want to address this somehow. I need to make multiple requests to the server while the UI is being rendered (UI renders multiple graphs).

I found [this article](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html) and I am exploring how to make best of use of this for my situation.

Is there any alternative friends?

Comment: Flash Player 11.4 (recently released) introduces a feature called  "Actionscript workers" where you can make worker threads and do stuff in the background.

Answer (score 0):

1) in flash **ALL** remote calls (like `RemoteObject`, `URLLoader`, `HTTPService` etc) are **asynchronous**. So you do not need any multi-threading for server request - UI will not be frozen!

2) In FlashPlayer 11.4 and Air 3.4 multi-treading became possible, but not really used yet in known applications...
See these:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_114_air_34_release_notes.html
http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4423

3) also, it is possible to avoid UI freezing for long process operations in flash using delays and calling over timeouts, like in example of asynchronous JPEG encoder:

[Fast or asynchronous AS3 JPEG encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509554/fast-or-asynchronous-as3-jpeg-encoding)

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-tutorial-an-asynchronous-jpeg-encoder

http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=201