# Timer vs setTimeout

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

The docs for flash.utils.setTimeout() state:

> Instead of using this method, consider
>   creating a Timer object, with the
>   specified interval, using 1 as the
>   repeatCount parameter (which sets the
>   timer to run only once).

Does anyone know if there is a (significant) advantage in doing so? Using setTimeout is a lot easier when you only need to delay 1 call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`setTimeout` actually uses a `Timer` subclass, the `SetIntervalTimer`, which is an internal class. You can check by doing `setTimeout(function ():void { throw "booom"; }, 1);`. You'll see it in the stack trace.

As such, I cannot really see a big disadvantage. The only difference is, that you have 2 anonymous calls instead of one. OTOH, in performance critical situations, you shouldn't be using either (except one internal timer) to avoid frequent instantiation of `TimerEvent` objects.

Basically, I think it's a matter of taste. Adobe decided, the AS3 event system is the shizzle, so they promote it.

Answer (score 8):

**Timer:**

- Gives you more control as you can
  register more event listeners to
  receive the event rather than a
  single one with setTimeout
- You can control the start time and
  the number of repetitions ( not very 
  useful against setTimeout, as this
  has to run just once and after a
  delay considering the immediate time 
  it was called)
- More lines to write, even more if you
  need to differentiate with parameters
  ( custom event class for this )
- Use of event listeners which is
  standard practice in as3.
- Cleaner look

**setTimeout:**

- Easier to use
- Less code to write
- Parameters can be easily sent;

I prefer the Timer class but I've seen setTimeout being frequently used by programmers.

Also if you are using Tweening libraries,some support delayed call

For example TweenMax
TweenMax.delayedCall(2, myFunction, ["myParam"]);

For all those who say that setTimeout is deprecated, this is non sense..

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout%28%29

I believe you can't see any "deprecated" keyword around setTimeout here

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout is working perfectly well in external .as files.

Just use this in the class :

```
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that setTimeout is depreciated in AS3. I'm having a bit of trouble finding the source of the setTimeout code, but I also believe it's easier to clear up any references to the Timer object, than with setTimeout (if I remember correctly from AS2).

Answer (score 0):

Usually something becomes deprecated if there becomes new and more powerful way to achieve something.

Yes setTimeout is much more easier to setup in some cases, but it is much more limited in other cases.

I would use the Timer class, because usually when something is deprecated, it means support may be removed for it sometime in the future, and then your code won't work.

Comment: generally a good reasoning, but unlikely to happen with flash player. adobe really cares a lot about backward compatibility and legacy support. also, in this case, one can rewrite the function within a couple of lines.

Comment: @back2dos, yes you are right in the case with Adobe, but why not follow good practices in general?

Comment: what other than Adobe's opinion makes timers a better practice than `setTimeout`? I agree, a `Timer` offers more possibilities then `setInterval` and `setTimer`, but then again, AVM2 bytecode offers more possibilities than ActionScript :D I think `setTimeout` is a useful function. If it weren't there, I'd write it on my own. To me, it is good practice for code to be concise, because that makes it readable and understandable. so while I generally agree, deprecation is usually to be taken seriously, in the case of ActionScript 3, I often feel it's really just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the Timer object is not at all accurate, and is subject to framerate fluctuations. Read http://forums.adobe.com/message/892631. I created my own Timer (called RealTimer) using the `Date` object and it is much more accurate. I recommend doing the same.

Answer (score -2):

setTimeout is not working in external .as files.

Comment: hi . nice to see you here :) anyway: could you go a little more into detail? what do you mean by "external"?

Comment: By external .as files i mean classes. Is anyone here using as3 without classes?
PS: Do we know each other?

Comment: Strange. Works perfectly for me, no matter whether compiled with the IDE or mxmlc. PS: not personally, but from the haXe mailing list. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misinformation then, seems i can't reproduce it myself. Probably the compiler was confused by another error and gave me this one. Was for a flash project after 2 years of programming only in haxe :P

Comment: I was just going to correct you after a talk with Virusescu :)

Comment: setTimeout works perfectly in any .as file. Just import flash.utils.setTimeout