# How do you stop setInterval() after certain number of iterations

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I have tried following code and its working  but how do i stop when its reach 130 ?

```
var textValue:Number = 67.1;
var addValue:Number = .1;

my_txt.text = textValue.toString();

function counter(){
    textValue += addValue;
    my_txt.text = textValue.toString();
}

setInterval(counter, 10);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setInterval returns a unique ID as an unsigned int (`uint`). You can use clearInterval with this ID to stop the interval. The code:

```
var textValue:Number = 67.1;
var addValue:Number = .1;
var myInterval:uint;
function counter(){
    textValue += addValue;
    my_txt.text = textValue.toString();
    if( textValue >= 130 ) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}
myInterval = setInterval( counter, 10 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stop an interval by using clearInterval. Try this:

```
var textValue:Number = 67.1;
var addValue:Number = .1;

my_txt.text = textValue.toString();

function counter(){
    textValue += addValue;
    my_txt.text = textValue.toString();
    //check for end value
    if (textValue>=130)
    {
        //clear the interval
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
}

//store the interval id for later
var intervalID:uint = setInterval(counter, 10);
```

Comment: 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before end of program.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like you may be using actionscript 3, I suggest not using an interval at all. A Timer object may be better as it can offer better control, such being able to set the number of times it fires off before stopping itself and being able to easily start, stop, and restart the timer as needed.

Example of using a Timer object and adding an event listener for each tick

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

// each tick delay is set to 1000ms and it'll repeat 12 times
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 12);

function timerTick(inputEvent:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("timer ticked");

    // some timer properties that can be accessed (at any time)
    trace(timer.delay); // the tick delay, editable during a tick
    trace(timer.repeatCount); // repeat count, editable during a tick
    trace(timer.currentCount); // current timer tick count;
    trace(timer.running); // a boolean to show if it is running or not
}
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTick, false, 0, true);
```

Controlling the timer:

```
timer.start(); // start the timer
timer.stop(); // stop the timer
timer.reset(); // resets the timer
```

Two events it throws:

```
TimerEvent.TIMER // occurs when one 'tick' of the timer has gone (1000 ms in the example)
TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE // occurs when all ticks of the timer have gone (when each tick has happened 11 times in the example)
```

API Documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Comment: For what it's worth setTimeout actually uses a Timer object behind the scenes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683398/timer-vs-settimeout The performance difference between a Timer and setTimeout is negligible but the important thing is to consolidate timing events to the fewest possible number of timer objects